# Are multilines regexp compatible with iterators?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, iterator

Iterators and generators are now a standard for memory efficient code. I am now trying to apply them as much as I can whenever I need to deal with long lists. Is there a way to use multiline regexp while iterating over large files (>500Mb) through an iterator?

**Classical Way:**

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r'some text', re.MULTILINE)

with open('my_large_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read() # Stores the whole text in a list
                    # This is memory consuming    
result = my_regex.findall(text)
```

**Iterator Way:**

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r'some text', re.MULTILINE)

with open('my_large_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # Use the file as an iterator and
                   # loop over the lines
                   # What could I do?
```

**Minimal Working Example:**

*Big file:*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor. 
--------------------------------
Some text I want to capture
--------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor.
```

*My regex:*

```
my_regex = re.compile(r"[-]+$\n(.+)\n\s[-]+", re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: You do not need a regex to match *that* kind of pattern, you may just check if the line is all hyphens, set the flag, save the next line, and if the next is also all hyphens, append to the resulting list. You will probably get stuck with iterator way if your patterns are arbitrary.

Comment: What difference do you think the multline option makes in this?

Comment: Is it because you want to iterate over the lines of the file instead of reading the whole thing in, but the multiline regexp needs multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is iterate over the file lines, and concatenate them to a running text, which you test with the regexp. When you find a match you can empty the running text.

```
text = ''
results = []
with open('my_large_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        text += line
        result = my_regex.findall(text)
        if result:
            results += result
            text = ''
```